# Issue with decoding YUV Image on some Android devices

Tags: android, image-processing, yuv

I was trying to create online scanner using android onPreviewFrame method. I've created AsyncTask to process image for me. This is the code of my converting method:

```
public Bitmap renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    byte[] yuv = yuvData;
    int inputOffset = top * dataWidth + left;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int outputOffset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int grey = yuv[inputOffset + x] & 0xff;
                pixels[outputOffset + x] = 0xFF000000 | (grey * 0x00010101);
            }
            inputOffset += dataWidth;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Everything works great on some devices, like HTC Desire HD, Samsung galaxy S2 or Samsung Galaxy GT or LG-P500. Some frames are correctly sent to server in greyscale and processed.

But on some devices like HTC One X everything goes wrong. Instead of real image server recieves images like this: [bad image](http://pandora.itraff.pl/~mszajek/photo.jpg)

I was trying to change Image Format - nothing changed (now I am using default one - NV21). I was trying to use YuvImage class and method compressToJpeg - nothing changed. Image is still wrong decoded.
I was trying to save image on SD Card but saved images were corrupted also.

Comment: Had a similar problem. In my case it wasn't the preview frames but the actual photo. I've worked around it by setting a different picture resolution. Check if chaning the preview resolution changes anything. I would also make sure that your preview aspect ratio matches the picture aspect ratio as I've had some problems with that aswell. The android.hardware.camera.any hardware feature is also known to cause problems.